# Visual studio upgrade

Tags: visual-studio

I have a Visual studio web forms project that is written in vb.net 4.8. It was originally built in VS 2012. At some point, I got a free version of VS 2019 to try and opened the project. After a few weeks, I scrapped VS 2019. Now when I open the project in VS 2012, it churns for a moment and VS crashes.

VS must have upgraded my project to work with 2019 and added some pieces that don't work in VS 2012.

How do I downgrade the project so it opens in VS 2012? or can I rebuild the project so it works in VS 2012?

Comment: Restore from source control.  Or find the backup copy that the project converter created in the project directory.

Comment: 1. Check your git history, revert changes. 2. Visual Studio 2012 is not supported anymore. Why don't you migrate to the latest version: Visual Studio 2022?

Comment: I don't see a backup copy. What is source control? What is git history? I even tried previous versions on the folder, but found none. It was probably September that it got converted. I doubt previous versions go back that far. I did try creating a new project and bringing the files in, but VS 2012 told me there were to many errors to list and I'm not even sure what the errors mean.

Comment: Could be something to do with the .NET version? I had some serious problems when VS2022 replaced .NET 6 with .NET 7.

Comment: It might also simply be the C# version. You're probably going to have to bite the bullet, upgrade to VS2022, and lump having to fix all the errors. There are bound to be breaking errors when migrating eleven year old code to the latest framework and language version.

Comment: @RobotHead VS 2019/2022 pays extra attention when upgrading a .NET Framework based project, so what you described can be irrelevant.

Comment: Learn about source control (of which git is a popular example). Then you can go back to previous versions

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out the solution.

I created a new project in VS 2012.

I had a backup copy of my project from a few months ago and copied all the files in and added them to the project. I then tried to build the project and got a few errors which I corrected.

I then found the more recent version that I had been using in VS 2019 and copied the files that had changed since the backup to replace older files in my new project.

everything seems to be working. I'm not sure why I was getting a situation where the forms collection of a post from a form came up blank.

I'm planning to eventually upgrade to 2022 version and am wondering what if anything I should watch out for so I do not get into trouble again. Also, I will make a backup of the project before the upgrade.

Answer (score -2):

I tried downloading VS 2019 and opening the project. The project kept crashing VS. I created a new project in VS 2019 and imported the files. After adding them to the project, I had about 5 warning preventing the program from building. Once those were addressed, I could run the project. I will now have to upgrade to the latest version of VS.

I upgraded to VS 2022 and code that used to work in VS 2012 causes errors when running the program. For instance: sending form values via post, causes the program to not get the values when using request.form("field_name")

I then tried going back to Visual studio 2012 and the program kept crashing when building the project. I got past that by uninstalling all versions of VS except 2012. I can now compile and run projects. I do however still get wacky issues with the code. For instance: sending form values via post, causes the program to not get the values when using request.form("field_name")

The code that is acting funny works in the production environment on a separate server. IIS .net 4.8

Can you let me know if there might be a problem with .net 4.8 on my machine and how to fix it? BTW, the projects were originally written in .net 3.5 and then upgraded to 4.8 to get access to tls so I could connect to Microsoft 365 to send emails.

Comment: This is Stack Overflow where you should edit the question itself to add new information, not post something else as **answer**.

Comment: You want me to rewrite the question so the original set of answers make no sense to the new question? wouldn't it make more sense to start a new question since I've gone back to the 2012 version of VS and all the upgrade stuff is irrelevant?

Comment: "so the original set of answers make no sense", but **they are simply comments not answers, and comments can absolutely go out-of-date whenever the question adds more details.** Anyway, you can post new question if you like and that also meets Stack Overflow rules. Just don't break the rules.